# is there a way to annotate type with value in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, annotations

I want to implement a function that receives type information as argument.
I'd like to use the argument to annotate local data in the function, like so:

```
function howto(someType: any){
  let data: someType; // error ts(2749)
  // ...
  // process data according to its type...
  // need (typeof data) information
}
```

I'd like to use it like so:

```
class SomeClass {
  //...
}

howto(SomeClass)

class OtherClass {
  //...
}

howto(OtherClass);
```

Is there a way to work around the ts(2749) error? or alternative implementation approach?

[Add] Actually, I have to write function `howto` like so:

```
function howto(someType: any){
  let data: someType; // error ts(2749)
  // ...
  const m: (d: (typeof data)) =>  void = (d) => { 
    // my implementation
  }
  thirdParyFunctionCall(m);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use generics?

Comment: @oldcook And what are you going to do with it (with `someType` or `data` variable)?

Comment: @Aleksey I added information on the question about what I am going to do with the data.

Comment: Still not showing how the `d` parameter is used. Are you doing `instanceof` or `new` for example?

Comment: Yes, initialize like `data = new (typeof data)` if it is possible.